# I want to do DOM manipulation like we do in jquery but in Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, dom-manipulation

I want to change the background-color of the parent div by the click of the button.

```
<div>
    <p>I want to change the background-color of the parent div by the click of the button.
    </p>
   <button (click)="changeColour()" id="buy-now">BUY NOW</button>
<div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a class to the parent div conditionally (`[class.red]="isRed"`) and change the condition when calling the `changeColor()` function (`isRed = true`).

Answer (score 0):

Don't think of it like JQuery!

But a more detailed answer:

Your HTML would use an expression for the class

```
<div [ngClass]="{'blue' : isBlue }"> 
    <p>I want to change the background-color of the parent div by the click of the button.
    </p>
   <button (click)="changeColour()" id="buy-now">BUY NOW</button>
<div>
```

And then your TypeScript would toggle the value. You can also use expressions / class names as needed:

```
export class AppComponent  {
isBlue = false;
  changeColour() {
    this.isBlue = !this.isBlue;
    console.log(this.isBlue);
  }
  name = 'Angular';
}
```

[See working example:](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rzdiex)

Comment: not this way, you are changing the value of isBlue, suppose it is there in many divs, then what?

Comment: @FurquanSaifi Then you could use an array, or an expression on the array, or custom modules / directives so that each div is it's own object with the properties your concerned with. This *is* the way you should approach it, direct DOM manipulation is bad. Also, your code doesn't even suggest a model you are using, or many potential divs.